# Lazy load with Unveil.js and Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I need to get on the 10 images from the database for the publication using unveyl.zhs. Prompt how can I request every time a new batch of this, for example 0-10, 11 - 21, 22-32 ...

```
Database structure
Pictures:
id int(8)
picture varchar(255)

$pictures = Pictures::model()->findAll();

foreach($pictures as $picture) {
    ... picture code ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findAll()` function accept criterias. You can set an offset and limit :

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->offset = 0;
$criteria->limit = 10;

$pictures = Pictures::model()->findAll( $criteria);
```

Here is the documentation of [DbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#limit-detail).